# Which activities will be cleared from memory by GC?

Tags: android, memory

Suppose I have 3 activities **Demo1**, **Demo2**, **Demo3** and a class **GlobalClass**

**GlobalClass**

```
 public Class GlobalClass{
 public static int staticVar = 1;
}
```

**Demo1**

```
public Class Demo1 extends Activity{
onCreate(){
  if(buttonClicked = 1){
    openDemo2();}
  else{
    openDemo3();}
  }
}
```

**Demo2**

```
public Class Demo2 extends Activity{
 int var = 10;
 onCreate(){
  GlobalClass.staticVar = var;
 }
}
```

**Demo3**

```
public Class Demo3 extends Activity{
  onCreate(){
    int var = GlobalClass.staticVar;
  }
}
```

So now lets assume we are at Demo1 and we open Demo2 first. Then we close Demo2,come back to Demo1 and open Demo3. Then we also close Demo3 and come back to Demo1.

- So at this point which activity/activities will be in the memory
  after GC?
- Will the whole view(Layout of that activity) for that activity saved
  in the memory?
- Will static variable make any difference?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot assume anything specific about GC.  It's based on demands of the process and use of the objects.  Note that GC is not the same as Android's low memory handling, which will completely tear down and destroy unused processes.  In your example of Demo1 -> Demo2 -> Demo3 there is a chance that none of them are reclaimed or garbage collected.  As Demo1 starts Demo2, Demo1 is paused and stopped but is still resident in memory for your app's process.  When Demo2 exits and returns to Demo1, Demo2 is exited via BACK button (causes `onDestroy()` to be called) then Demo2 and its related memory should go through GC.  But, it also depends on what you do in Demo2.  It's entirely possible to accidentally leak objects if you are not careful.

Comment: Actually i needed to know if the activity in which static variable is referenced or from which the static variable got value, which one of it would stay in the memory?

Comment: Main point here is the static variable. I need to know will static variable make any difference?

Comment: It's a very bad idea to share static data between activities since they have independent lifecycles. That being said, the class you have created with a static field used by all of the classes should exist as long as one of the activities exists.